# Change location of Chrome extension background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a question on chrome extension background. I wanna use background to load other website to parse data I want and pass it to my tab use Message API.

But, I have no idea to load the webpage in background, I don't want to use `iframe`.
First, I tried the `window.location.href` to change, but it didn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without an iframe. Why do you want to avoid it? If you need to parse non-dynamic data, XHR can serve you well.

Comment: First, thanks for you response. I have tried iframe to get webpage successfully but I only got html data by javascript. I have no idea to get the dynamic data from iframe.

Comment: Please clarify what type of data are you trying to obtain.

Comment: The data might be generated from the back-end of website. I didn't know how to get this kind of data. Sorry for newbie question. Thanks, again.

Comment: "Might be"? Specifics, please. Is it in dynamically added DOM? Is it in JS context of the page? **What** are you looking to extract?

Comment: Yes, it's dynamically add DOM and I also found the JS file in webpage. I just want to obtain some picture URL, trying to use chrome-extension context-script arrange them and watch them conveniently. Of cause I know how to extract the data i want from JS. But, I just looking for a easy way to get the data dynamically add DOM.